# Image filtering with MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

My objective is to filter the image of a bubble in a tube to posteriorly aplly the filters close connections (morphologic) and fill center of objects in order to close the bottom part of the bubble (threshold image), finding thus the area of the bubble relative to the area of the tube. However, i don't know of any other filter that i can use before the threshold filter to improve the filtering, because the image still has a lot of noise. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

[Tube with the bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x597O.jpg)

[Cropped image with the bubble to be delineated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJlYc.jpg)

[Grayscale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVmeO.jpg)

[Threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HECus.jpg)

```
    % Reading the image
    image = imread('bubble.jpg');
    figure, imshow(image);

    % Cropping the image
    cropped = imcrop(image,[320 0 1100 1080]);
    figure, imshow(cropped);

    % Transforming the image to grayscale
    gray = rgb2gray(cropped);
    figure, imshow(gray);

    % Threshold filter
    thresh = im2bw(gray, 0.5)
    figure, imshow(thresh);
```

Comment: Could you show what the bubble is and what the total area is? I have no idea what I’m looking at in that picture. What needs to be measured?

Comment: I'm guessing this is some sort of experimental set up you have? If so, do you have any control over the framing and lighting of the image? The background colour seems to be fairly distinct, so it might be easiest to have a threshold specifically for the background, subtract that, and the bubble should be the largest remaining blob. Again, this depends heavily on your setup / where these images are coming from.

Comment: Hi Cris Luengo! Sorry for that! It's allready attached on the text. The total area is the area of the whole image. What needs to be measured is the direct relation between the area of the bubble and the area of the image.

Comment: I no longer have control over this experiment as i am far from it. Exactly Dominic! but i need an another filter so i can delineate only the bubble on that figure.

Comment: Sorry Cris, its the relation between the area of the bubble to the area of the tube.

Comment: You should type `@cris` in your comment so that I get a notification. Otherwise it's up to luck whether I see your question again... :)

Comment: This is a really hard problem, I can't suggest a solution in the space of an SO answer. I would start by improving the imaging. If you don't have control over that, you'd have to collect a large set of samples, manually mark the bubble area, and train some machine learning tool to replicate your markings.

Comment: Ok @cris Sorry for that!

Comment: I know that i can do it, but i don't know what type of filter i can use before the threshold filter so i can better filter my images.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Here's something you can try: 1) After grayscale, apply a moving average filter to blur out the small scale noise. You will need to trial/error the filter size, but 5-10 pixels looks like it may blur out the streaks in the  tube. 2) After your threshold, you can try using bwconncomp() to identify the connected white blobs. 3) use regionprops() to find the convex hull (i.e. bounding polygon) of the largest object (presumably the main bubble), and then calculate the area of the convex hull.